# PostgreSQL partial index not used depending on boolean comparison

Tags: postgresql, index-tuning, postgresql-9.6

I need help understanding why a partial index would be used in one query and would not in second one which is effectively the same.

I have the following table:

```
     Column     |           Type           | Collation | Nullable |   Default
----------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+-------------
 id             | text                     |           | not null |
 field1         | text                     |           | not null |
 field2         | text                     |           | not null |
 field3         | boolean                  |           | not null |  false
```

With a partial index:

```
CREATE INDEX idx__my_table_index
    ON my_table(field1, field2)
    WHERE field3 IS FALSE;
```

and the following two queries:

```
postgres=> explain select distinct field1, field2 from my_table where not field3;
-[ RECORD 1 ]----------------------------------------------------------------------------
QUERY PLAN | Unique  (cost=113849.28..113849.66 rows=36 width=29)
-[ RECORD 2 ]----------------------------------------------------------------------------
QUERY PLAN |   ->  Sort  (cost=113849.28..113849.37 rows=38 width=29)
-[ RECORD 3 ]----------------------------------------------------------------------------
QUERY PLAN |         Sort Key: field1, field2
-[ RECORD 4 ]----------------------------------------------------------------------------
QUERY PLAN |         ->  Seq Scan on my_table  (cost=0.00..113848.28 rows=38 width=29)
-[ RECORD 5 ]----------------------------------------------------------------------------
QUERY PLAN |               Filter: (NOT field3)
```

and the second:

```
postgres=> explain select distinct field1, field2 from my_table where field3 IS FALSE;
-[ RECORD 1 ]-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
QUERY PLAN | Unique  (cost=0.14..13.03 rows=36 width=29)
-[ RECORD 2 ]-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
QUERY PLAN |   ->  Index Only Scan using idx__my_table_index on reservation  (cost=0.14..12.75 rows=38 width=29)
```

P.S. I'm using PostgreSQL 9.6

Comment: What happens if you create the index with `WHERE field3 = FALSE`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exact laws of the game can be found [in the manual, chapter **Partial Indexes**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-partial.html):

> To be precise, a partial index can be used in a query only if the
>   system can recognize that the `WHERE` condition of the query
>   mathematically implies the predicate of the index. PostgreSQL does not
>   have a sophisticated theorem prover that can recognize mathematically
>   equivalent expressions that are written in different forms. (Not only
>   is such a general theorem prover extremely difficult to create, it
>   would probably be too slow to be of any real use.) The system can
>   recognize simple inequality implications, for example “x < 1” implies
>   “x < 2”; **otherwise the predicate condition must exactly match part of
>   the query's `WHERE` condition or the index will not be recognized as usable**.

Bold emphasis mine.

Accordingly, the query predicate `where not field3` is not recognized as matching the index predicate `where field3 IS FALSE`, so the query *planner* does not consider it.

Answer (score 1):

These queries may have slightly different semantics, from the query parser point of view.

`select ... where field3 IS FALSE` means "evaluate expression `field3 IS FALSE` and return rows for which the evaluation result is `TRUE`". The expression matches that of your partial index, so it's a natural choice.

`select ... where not field3` means "evaluate expression `NOT field3` and return rows for which the evaluation result is `TRUE`". Here the expression does *not* match the partial index.

*We* know that these expressions are logically equivalent, particularly in the presence of the `NOT NULL` constraint on the column in question, but the parser (or the optimizer) apparently cannot see that.

I suspect if you change your partial index condition to `WHERE NOT field3` you'll see that the plans for your two queries switch places.